# Sample water for lead

Tags: water

On many websites, they recommend sampling your water after at least 8 hours of no usage.  Some recommend sampling immediately after this period and others recommend flushing the water for 5-15 minutes.  I'm almost sure there are lead connections in the plumbing system because the apartment building was built in the 1930s.  And the city says the water meets lead standards at the source (in other words, the 5-15 minute flush seems unnecessary). Does it make sense to just flush for 30 seconds before sampling because 30 seconds is how long I plan to flush before using the water for cooking, washing, bathing etc?

(Actually I'm testing for more than just lead)

Answer (score 2):

In the 30's they still used lead quite a bit, lead solder was used into the 70's for copper pipe. In my early years I had removed lead pipes and drains most of these homes were a bit earlier Victorians but there have been a few cabins that we remodeled that were from the late 20's early 30's and most was on a 2nd or 3rd remodel and mostly the drains were lead but we did find a few lead pipes on drinking water pipes in angels camp California. Running the water for a few seconds similar to normal ussage is a good idea to get a idea what is in the water because even copper pipe from the early 70's may have lead solder joints, if the water is run for a short time the lead levels will be much lower.

Answer (score 1):

As to your testing methods; if you WANT to find out if there is lead present, take the sample immediately. If your goal is to show little or no lead in the sample, run the water for 15 minutes. The issue is that lead takes time to "leach" out of the solder joints into the water in any appreciable amounts. So by running the line for 15 minutes, you are flushing the lead laden water down the drain BEFORE you test it.

The same by the way will apply to your use. If you are concerned about ingesting too much lead, don't drink or cook with water that has been sitting in the pipes for too long, run the water for a while before using it.

Comment: I would ask who would run there water for 15 minutes prior to bathing or getting a glass of water? Run the water long enough to flush your own plumbing but not the entire city water system!